# Get value of Post in Array Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm trying to get Post values of an array textbox name in Wordpress. The code is:

```
<input checked="checked" id="simple_fields_fieldgroups_9_1_0" type="checkbox" name="simple_fields_fieldgroups[9][1][0]" value="1">
```

How can I get the value of `simple_fields_fieldgroups[9][1][0]` using POST? When I try `$_POST['simple_fields_fieldgroups[9][1][0]']` it will simply not work..

UPDATE:

When I do

```
print_r($_POST['post_category']);
```

I get

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 18 [2] => 1 )
```

How can I get the value 18?

Comment: Why is the field name `simple_fields_fieldgroups[9][1][0]`?

Comment: @sdexp It's from wordpress

Answer (score 1):

If it's posting properly, it should be accessible as:

```
<?php
    $x = $_POST['simple_fields_fieldgroups'][9][1][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use a for each to iterate through the array?

```
    foreach ($_POST['post_category'] as $key => $value) {
              var_dump($value);
    }
    die();
```

Otherwise the you can get the value by using:

```
$_POST['post_category'][1]
```

That's because since $_POST['post_category'] is an array, you can dump out the value using the value's key within the array.

Comment: You could also try dumping out the $key as well.

Comment: $_POST['post_category'][1] should get the value 18 you are looking for.